# How Remote Debugging Works Internally

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have successfully implemented my remote debugging for Spring boot applications in tomcat server for several times.
To make remote debug enable in tomcat server just need to change in catalina.sh and set: 
 `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999 $JSSE_OPTS"`

And start tomcat by `catalina.sh jpda start`

But I need to know how it works internally through this specific port over **TCP** network connection from IDE?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html and https://stackify.com/java-remote-debugging/ ?

Comment: yes I checked it but it says "Currently, the JDWP does not specify any mechanism for transport rendezvous or any directory services". And by going through this docs I am not get clear concepts how it works @CrazyCoder

Comment: What exactly are you trying to learn and what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I want to know the full mechanism of JDWP @CrazyCoder

Comment: Check the JDK source code, start from the `jdb` utility.